# Join data from 2 String dimensions in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am wondering if any of you can help me on my problem.
I have a table containing money exchanges between individuals. Thus, the table is composed of columns ID A and ID B, which are unique IDs, and another column with an integer, a price.

My problem is that I want to perform the sum of the integer for a precise individual and I can find the same individual either in column ID A or ID B because the software is putting IDs in random columns. Therefore, I have 2 dimensions ID A and ID B.

I have some experience in Tableau but I am in a dead end on this one.
Do you have any idea ?

Thanks a lot !
Julien

Comment: If the individuals in the columns are the same people then you should restructure the data in the following way. Create a table with just a single ID column but a separate column categorising whether they sent or received money and a single price column. You will now be able to sum by individual (either the net total, the sent total or the received total).

Comment: You got it Matt, that's exactly what I did : Make a custom SQL request to fuse the 2 ID columns. In the end you have the double of columns but hey that's what I wanted ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt got the answer. Make a custom SQL request to fuse the 2 ID columns. In the end you have the double of columns but hey that's what I wanted ;)
Also, it seems to be the most reasonable way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to sum one individual at a time, use a parameter for the IDs.

Something like the following:

```
sum(IF [PARAMETER_ID] = [ID_A] THEN [PRICE] END)
+
sum(IF [PARAMETER_ID] = [ID_B] THEN [PRICE] END)
```